# Working with binary files in MATLAB: load as-is to memory and interpret later

Tags: matlab, memory, optimization, io, fread

I have some binary files (obtained from a camera), in which frames are stored in some sequential order.

The usual algorithm to working with such files would be something along the lines of: `open file -> advance to first frame -> read frame -> advance a few bits until the next frame -> read next frame` and so on. Intuitively, this results in many "short" I\O operations that likely reduce performance when compared with a single "long" operation.

For this reason, it seemed natural to me to initially load the file into memory, and interpret it later "at my leisure" (since reading from RAM is supposed to be much faster than from disk).

So far, I could think of two possible solutions to this problem:

1. The submission [`mfile` in the FileExchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16634-memory-file--mfile-). *{Even though it looks exactly like what I need, I'm slightly reluctant to use this solution because it's about 7 years old (which invites the assumption that it may be outdated)}*
2. Using a ["Ram Disk"](http://www.starwindsoftware.com/high-performance-ram-disk-emulator) to hold the files, and then use the standard MATLAB I\O tools.

My question is: **Is there some built-in functionality in MATLAB that allows to achieve this result?**

Comment: `fread` is capable of reading binary data into a matrix of class `uint8`.  But that vector won't be usable by functions which expect to read files.  In general, though, the OS disk cache should read ahead and minimize the cost of multiple short operations.

Comment: @Ben - It's true that I should've mentioned whether or not I wanted to keep the functionality of "`functions which expect to read files`". I'd say that keeping the functionality is preferred but not a must - it's just that I'm not sure how to convert uint8 into the multitude of datatypes that the file contains (`int16`, `int32`, `float`, `char`, `uint16`, `uint32`), so this will just result in some extra work later on. || If it's alright with you, I'll edit this into the question as a 3rd possible solution.

Comment: I'd recommend not bothering.  If the entire file fits in memory, then the disk cache will fit it all, and the OS will automatically map your file operations to memory operations.  If you were reading a pixel at a time, then yes, fixing that layer would help.  Since you're reading a frame at a time, this is unlikely to buy you much.

Comment: If you insist, you can read the whole file as uint8, then use the builtin `typecast` to deserialize the correct elements of that uint8 vector to your correct types.

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestions of `@Ben Voigt` and `@Peter`, I tried writing some code that reads the binary file to memory and parses it. Below is a comparison of a piece of the original code and my "from memory" implementation that produces the same result (this is just the header and not the frames themselves, but the idea is similar +reshape).

I'd like to point out the documentation in `fread.m` is very concise and informative.

#### Original Code (w/o comments)

```
fid=fopen(fName,'r');

fseek(fid, 11, 'bof');
ptw.m_MainHeaderSize=fread(fid,1,'int32');
ptw.m_FrameHeaderSize=fread(fid,1,'int32');

fseek(fid, 27, 'bof');
ptw.m_nframes=fread(fid,1,'int32');

fseek(fid, 212 , 'bof');
ptw.m_fHousingTemp=fread(fid,1,'float');
fseek(fid, 216 , 'bof');
ptw.m_fHousingTemp2=fread(fid,1,'float');

fseek(fid, 245, 'bof');
ptw.m_minlut=fread(fid,1,'int16');
ptw.m_maxlut=fread(fid,1,'int16');
```

#### "From-memory" Equivalent

```
function dts = InterpretFromMemory(fName)
%% Definitions
UINT8_IN_CHAR = 1;
UINT8_IN_INT16 = 2;
UINT8_IN_INT32 = 4; 
UINT8_IN_FLOAT = 4;
ZERO_POS = 1;
%% Initialization
dts = struct('m_filename',fName);
%% Reading
fid=fopen(fName);
fComplete = fread(fid,'*uint8'); 
fclose(fid);
%% Parsing
curr_pos = 11;
dts.m_MainHeaderSize = readFromArrayAndAdvance(fComplete,1,'int32');
dts.m_FrameHeaderSize = readFromArrayAndAdvance(fComplete,1,'int32');

curr_pos = 27;
dts.m_nframes = readFromArrayAndAdvance(fComplete,1,'int32');

curr_pos = 212;
dts.m_fHousingTemp  = readFromArrayAndAdvance(fComplete,1,'float');
dts.m_fHousingTemp2 = readFromArrayAndAdvance(fComplete,1,'float');

curr_pos = 245;
dts.m_minlut = readFromArrayAndAdvance(fComplete,1,'int16');
dts.m_maxlut = readFromArrayAndAdvance(fComplete,1,'int16');

function [out]=readFromArrayAndAdvance(hArray,numVals,valType)
    switch valType
        case 'char'
            numBytes = UINT8_IN_CHAR;
        case {'int16','uint16'}
            numBytes = UINT8_IN_INT16;
        case {'int32','uint32'}
            numBytes = UINT8_IN_INT32;  
        case 'float'
            numBytes = UINT8_IN_FLOAT;
            valType = 'single'; %// float equivalent supported by typecast
    end
    out = typecast(hArray(...
        curr_pos+ZERO_POS:curr_pos+ZERO_POS+numVals*numBytes-1),valType);
    curr_pos = curr_pos + numVals*numBytes;
end

end
```

**TODO:** I intend to run some benchmarks on this in the future and compare the various methods.

---

Copyright notice: the "original code" snippet belongs to [FLIR](http://www.flir.com).